# mlr3 hyperband: unused argument (clone = character())

Tags: mlr3

I want to code some hyperband tuning in mlr3. I started with running the subsample-rpart hyperband example from chapter 4.4 in mlr3 book - directly copied from there. I am getting an error:
Error in benchmark(design, store_models = self$store_models, allow_hotstart = self$allow_hotstart,  :
unused argument (clone = character())

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), preferably using the [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `mlr3` 0.13.1 from CRAN.

```r
install.packages("mlr3")
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I had version 0.13.0.